# Ubuntu 12.04 How To Run Python 3.3.2 Program In Terminal

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

OK so for school I am having to set up a computer using Ubuntu 12.04 to run Python programs written in Python 3.3. I was aware that 12.04 came with Python 3.2, so I followed the procedure in the first reply in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244544/how-to-install-python-3-3) to install Python 3.3:

Now when I open the Terminal, I type `~/bin/py` to get it to display the following at the top of the terminal:

```
Python 3.3.2 (default, Dec 10 2013, 11:35:01)
[GCC 4.6.3] on Linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits", or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

So far so good. Now I am having trouble replicating the functionality of the same Python program that I execute as follows on my Windows laptop.

(This is what I type in the Python commandline on windows)

```
import filereader 
from filereader import * 
reader = filereader("C:\Python33\ab1copy.ab1") 
reader.show_entries()
```

The end result is a directory of data types found in the file. The filereader class is located in `Python33\Lib\site-packages\filereader.py` in the above example. On the Ubuntu computer its location is `Python-3.3.2\Lib\site-packages\filereader.py`. Also on Ubuntu, the `ab1copy.ab1` file is located in the home directory for now.

After I achieve the recognition of Python 3.3.2 in the Ubuntu Terminal as noted above, how can I replicate my program's functionality there?  If I try to put in the same first command "import filereader" I get the following error:

```
>>>import filereader
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'filereader'
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What error messages do you see?

Comment: import * looks strange, and of course you need to change the path to the file. But like Michael wrote, it's hard to help without knowing the problem.

Comment: What is the error? Keep in mind that Python3 is not backwards compatible.

Comment: I feel like `import *` isn't valid python on any system ... Are you sure that's what you type on windows?

Comment: `>>> import *` produces a SyntaxError. I'm guessing there's a missing `\n` between the first `filereader` and `from`, because `import filereader from filereader` isn't valid either.

Comment: This question is probably a duplicate of [one of these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+importerror)

Answer (score 1):

try this in the terminal

```
python3 your_file.py
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not in your python path.

Check this to see where it looks for your source:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```